# installing php5.3 with Opcache

Tags: php-5.3, opcache

I'm just curious if it is possible to have both php5.3 and OpCache mod. installed on Linux Debian based OS. I spent the almost all day searching over the internet to find out whether it is possible to or not to install php5.3 + OpCache. I don't want to use APC because OpCache is around 10% faster than APC.

any idea whether that can be achieved or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PECL version of Opcache still supports PHP 5.3, but it's worth running the Opcache test suite to ensure that your particular dot release doesn't have problems.